# How to get app version from apk file using JAVA eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, file, apk, version

Is there any way that I can get the app version from apk file

using JAVA eclipse?

thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the `apk` via 7zip/WinRAR and then open the folder with sublime and then look for `version`. You will get a hit if you are lucky.

The concrete way would be to [decompile it](https://codexplo.wordpress.com/2012/03/15/how-to-decompile-android-apk-to-java-source-code/) and then do a search.

Comment: thanks actually I also already tried with 7zip and tried to decode manifast file. Just wondering this job could be done through java code via eclipse

Comment: `Manifest` will only contain hashes of the files but not the version info. Usually the version info is written in about activity, which means decompiling is the only way. It is also possible it might end up in one of the `.xml` files depending on the situation.